# what is the best place to retrieve user data in android face book login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I did this to retrieve user data, not in `loginButton.registerCallback`but like below
and i noted `request.executeAsync();` this seems like an `async` if yes it runs out of the UI thread.

1.Is it works in that way ?

problem is when i run

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " +name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this runs(but name = null) and below that if i add an Intent it goes to the next activity but my retrieved data is null..

I removed the Intent added a debug point to the middle (lets say here --> `String gender = object.getString("gender");`)

now first toast got displayed(welcome null) then it came to the debug point and when i go line by line retrieved data got displayed in my Evaluater in debug mode.
which seems it takes time to load it / is it because async ?

any suggestion to retrieve  data before any other task (before toast).

where i went wrong :'(

```
     //Register a Callback
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                       @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            try {

                                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                                String email = object.getString("email");

                                                 name = object.getString("name");
                                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                String birthDay = object.getString("birthday");
                                                JSONObject pictureObject = object.getJSONObject("picture");
                                                JSONObject dataInPicture = pictureObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                                String pictureURLInData = dataInPicture.getString("url");



                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                System.out.println("ExceptionExceptionGraphRequest" + e);
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });

                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,name,gender, birthday,picture.type(large)");
                            parameters.putBoolean("redirect", false);
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

                            // App code
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " +name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
```

Comment: code at bottom where u work with bundle, "id,email"..  is not in a scope where it will be dispatched WITHIN the CallBack scope of the important CB within the FB GraphRequest.... if you want FB's name to be fetched and used then use it WITHIN the scope fo the FB.graphReq.Callback... IMO u are not doing that and you have undef null instead of the desired name.

Comment: thanks friend ! after your comment i add my intent and toast inside the GraphRequest below to  String pictureURLInData (thats my last data i retrieve ) and it worked ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way i solved my issue .. added comments for the changes that i have done !

```
//Register a Callback
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            try {

                                                System.out.println("LetsseewhatwegotForFB" + object.toString());
                                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                                Constants.FB_USER_ID =id;
                                                 name = object.getString("name");
                                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                String birthDay = object.getString("birthday");
                                                JSONObject pictureObject = object.getJSONObject("picture");
                                                JSONObject dataInPicture = pictureObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                                String pictureURLInData = dataInPicture.getString("url");
                                                Constants.SOCIAL_NETWORK_IMAGE_URL = pictureURLInData;
                                                System.out.println("urlData"+pictureURLInData);

                                                //--- after  retrieve data do your task but inside like this(inside),in below ,not after bundle
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " +name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                buttonToLoadDashboard.performClick();  // my intent 

                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                System.out.println("ExceptionExceptionGraphRequest" + e);
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });

                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            //--picture.type(large) increase the quality of image
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,name,gender, birthday,picture.type(large)");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        }
```